# Getting a NotSerializableException on a Serializable object?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm getting a `NotSerializableException` when running my app that is complaining about my `AbilityScore` class, but as you can see, the class, and all its members, are `Serializable` (even the enum, even though I don't think that's necessary).

Here is my code :

```
public class AbilityScore implements Serializable {
    private Scores type;
    public Scores getScoreType() { return type; }

    private int value;
    public int getScoreValue() { return value; }
    public void setScoreValue(int v) { value = v; }
    public int getScoreModifier() { return ((int)(value / 2) - 5); }

    private boolean proficient;
    public boolean isProficient() { return proficient; }
    public void setProficient(boolean p) { proficient = p; }

    public AbilityScore(Scores t, int v) {
        type = t;
        value = v;
    }

    public enum Scores implements Serializable {
        STRENGTH, DEXTERITY, CONSTITUTION, INTELLIGENCE, WISDOM, CHARISMA;
    }
}
```

This is the method causing the exception...

```
public void saveCharacter(Context context) {
    String filename = me.getFilename();

    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        //fout = new FileOutputStream(filename, false);
        fout = context.openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(me);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(oos != null) oos.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: Problem saving character to file => " + filename);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error saving character...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public CharacterInfo loadCharacter(Context context, String filename) {
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    CharacterInfo myCharacter = null;
    try {
        //fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        fin = context.openFileInput(filename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        myCharacter = (CharacterInfo) ois.readObject();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        if(ois != null) ois.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: Problem loading character from file => " + filename);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading character...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myCharacter;
}
```

Here's the stack trace for one of the files...

```
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err: java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.character.AbilityScore
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:778)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1488)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:759)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.GlobalState.loadCharacter(GlobalState.java:54)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.LoadCharacterActivity.findCharacters(LoadCharacterActivity.java:47)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.LoadCharacterActivity.onCreate(LoadCharacterActivity.java:32)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6056)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.character.AbilityScore
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1642)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.GlobalState.saveCharacter(GlobalState.java:35)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at edu.uml.android.adventurersarchive.CreateCharacterActivity.submitCharacter(CreateCharacterActivity.java:73)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19991)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-30 02:45:11.285 27048-27048/? W/System.err:  ... 6 more
```

And yes, `CharacterInfo` and every member inside is `Serializable`. It's specifically complaining about `AbilityScore` though. What's going on here?

Comment: What method is causing the exception?

Comment: Added the method code.

Comment: Please provide the entire stack trace in your question, and tell us the relationship between `CharacterInfo` and `AbilityScore`, and show the writing code.

Comment: CharacterInfo is a rather large class, so I'd rather not post the whole thing.  But CharacterInfo is a serializable class and it contains an array of AbilityScore objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace shows that you must have got a `NotSerializableException` when *writing* the object, before you had added `implements Serializable` to its definition.

You need to delete the serialized file and start again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

"private **Scores** type;
 public **Scores** getScoreType() { return type; }"

You have to implement Serializable in "Scores".